# Error during storing values in plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, plist

I have a stepper, during the change of its value I need to store the values in plist.

So according to saveAppPlist method I need to pass the NSMutableDictionary with the changed file -> dictData

```
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:dictData format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
if(plistData)
{
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
```

And here it is the method for the stepper:

```
-(void)changeItemQuantityAtRow:(int)row
                       toValue:(double)value
{
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [[items objectAtIndex:row] mutableCopy];
    [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:value] forKey:@"Quantity"];
    [items setObject:item atIndexedSubscript:row];
    NSLog(@"%@", items);
    NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:items forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name", @"Price", @"Quantity", nil]];
    NSLog(@"%@", plistDict);
    [self saveAppPlist:plistDict];
}
```

and the plist looks like this (this only one of 4 items):

```
<dict>
    <key>Items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>The zero item</string>
            <key>Price</key>
            <integer>133</integer>
            <key>Quantity</key>
            <integer>17</integer>
        </dict>
```

The stepper is changing the quantity of the item. But I have an error like this when I try to change the value of quantity:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (4) differs from count of keys (3)'
```

I understand the source of the error but don't know how can I solve this issue. Who can help me? And one more - may be it's not so good to store the value after every tap on the stepper?

Comment: your items array having 4 objects and you are giving three keys that s the problem once show me your items array data.

Comment: @Sunny I see but something is wrong with the logic.. I have 4 Items objects and each object has 3 values.. I just want to change the quantity of the 1 item.. How can I do that?

Comment: explain  the structure what you want?

Comment: @Sunny I need to change the value quantity of 1 of the 4 items and store the changed plist file. The typical structure of the item is in the post.

Comment: The method `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:` is used to store several objects with different keys at the dictionary, the arrays length must be the same as their values are paired. An original plist has another structure: there's a single object for the array.

Comment: @A-Live OK than and how can I solve this? In the method passed the value of the item and the number of the row, which displays the value.. -(void)changeItemQuantityAtRow:(int)row
                       toValue:(double)value

Comment: @ShurupuS I've posted solution as an answer below, it saves array as a single object. Please let me know if the output is not what you needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget that you want to store an array, think of the object as `id` instance. As you want to store `id items` with the key `@"Items"`, what you want to do is to use

```
//[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:<#(id)#> forKey:<#(id<NSCopying>)#>]
NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:items forKey:@"Items"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple way If I want to write some data in pList file

Plist file name is "**Contacts.plist**"
Storing the values for

1. Name
2. Address
3. Phone No.

You can find compile tutorial for how to work with plist file on below link

> [How to use PList files in iPhone Tutorial](http://rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-use-plist-files-in-iphone.html)

Below is the code example

```
- (void)saveDataInPlist {

    //get the plist document path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contacts.plist"];    

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *contentArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: plistFilePath])
    {
        NSLog(@"File does not exist");

        // If the file doesn’t exist, create an empty plist file        
        plistFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contacts.plist"];
        //NSLog(@"path is %@",plistFilePath);

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"File exists, Get data if anything stored");

        contentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];       
    }       


    NSString *name = nameTextField.text;
    NSString *address = addressTextField.text;
    NSString *phone = phoneTextField.text;


    //add values to dictionary
    [data setValue:name forKey:@"Name"];
    [data setValue:address forKey:@"Address"];
    [data setValue:phone forKey:@"PhoneNo"];

    //add dictionary to array
    [contentArray addObject:data];

    //write array to plist file
    if([contentArray writeToFile:plistFilePath atomically:YES]){

       NSLog(@"saved");  
     }
     else {
       NSLog(@"Couldn't saved");
    }
    }

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank u for the link - it's very helpful!

Comment: @ShurupuS really great to know that, the efforts I put was worthy :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the problem lyes with the dictionary construction.
You supply `items` as the values (each item may contain the `Name`,`Price` and `Quantity` keys) and as keys you supply the `item` keys.
You might need to change the construction to:
`[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[items] forKeys:@[@"Items"]]`

Comment: I thought it is a decision but now i have this.. 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (4) differs from count of keys (1)'

Comment: It would work if you used `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:items, nil]` as a first parameter. @ShurupuS Please take a few minutes to read all this methods description (a short description is available if you select one of autocompletion options and then `alt+click` the method), that will help you a lot in the future.